# Where should I store model-related view data in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, model, state

I'm using the following `isText` property to **switch between a dropdown and a text input field** in my view (combination of `ng-click="family.isText = !family.isText"` and `ng-show`), while iterating through all of the font families.

```
font = {
    name: null,
    style: null,
    families: [{
        name: null,
        parent: null,
        isText: true // <--
    }]
};
```

Here is the template I'm using:

```
<p  ng-repeat="family in file.font.families"
    ng-init="family.textInput = false">

        <!-- Default families input is selection -->
        <select ng-model="file.font.families[$index].name"
                ng-hide="family.textInput"
                ng-change="updateMainFamily($parent.$index, $index)">

            <option disabled value="">— Famille</option>
            <option ng-repeat="family in familiesList"
                    ng-value="family">

                {{ _.capitalize(family) }}
            </option>

        </select>

        <select ng-model="file.font.families[$index].parent"
                ng-hide="family.textInput">

            <option disabled value="">— Grande famille</option>
            <option ng-repeat="mainFamily in mainFamiliesList"
                    ng-value="mainFamily"
                    ng-selected="file.font.families[$parent.$index].parent == mainFamily">

                {{ _.capitalize(mainFamily) }}
            </option>

        </select>

        <!-- But can be switched to text input (ex: for adding a new family)  -->
        <input  type="text"
                class="family"
                ng-model="file.font.families[$index].name"
                ng-show="family.textInput">

        <input  type="text"
                class="family"
                ng-model="file.font.families[$index].parent"
                ng-show="family.textInput">

        <!-- ... with these buttons -->
        <button class="alt small"
                ng-click="family.textInput = !family.textInput"
                ng-hide="family.textInput">

            <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="alt small"
                ng-click="family.textInput = !family.textInput"
                ng-show="family.textInput">

            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
        </button>
</p>
```

I don't want to send this kind of data to my back-end when the user saves the model, as it only has a sense in the view context. On the other hand, I find it not handy to create a `familiesState`-like property to store them.

**What would be a good, clean way to store model-related view data in AngularJS?**

Comment: You could create a generic property whitelist or blacklist function and attach it to all of your models.  Call it before sending to the server.

Answer (score 2):

i think u could use a kind of content provider for this. And send it to your backend.

You can do this :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('some.module')
    .factory('myFontContentProvider', [contentProvider]);

function contentProvider() {
   var content = this;
   var name = null;
   var style = null;
   var families: [{
       name: null,
       parent: null
   }]

   content.setName = function(n) {
        name = n;
   }
   content.getName = function() {
        return name;
   }

   /* continue with your getters and setters here */

   return content;
}
```

Then in your controller, you do the mappind like this with your factory :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('some.module')
    .controller('yourController', ['myFontContentProvider',yourCtrl]);

function yourCtrl(contentProvider) {
   var vm = this;
   /* mapping here */
   vm.getName = contentProvider.getName;
   vm.setName = contentProvider.setName;
   /* etc */
}
```

And Finally in your DOM you have this :

```
<div ng-controller="yourController as ctrl"
<!-- to get your value -->
<span ng-bind="ctrl.getName()"></span>
<!-- etc -->
```

with some ng-click="ctrl.setYOURPROPERTY()" to call the factory function and set a value

Answer (score 0):

Your backend service should be able to scrape out the information you don't want to have in there but it is really hard to offer a good solution with so few details.  could you give us an example of  your html, your controller, and your service/factory?

Comment: I could do that in the backend, but I find it non-optimized to send data that I won't use anyway. I edited my post to add the HTML template.